# Why is my ValueEventListener not working?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read the values from the Firebase realtime database, but nothing is happening. I can't find out what's wrong with my code. I have set the rules accordingly. Following is the code in MainActivity.java

```
package com.borah.manjit.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String TAG="mn";
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("Games");
        tv=findViewById(R.id.tv);

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String s=dataSnapshot.child("game1").getValue(String.class);
                tv.setText(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Here is the data in my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DRaK.png)

The rules of the data base are set to the following

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Should not the textview's text be set to "Cricket" ?

This is what my log looks like

> 09-10 13:34:52.854 23293-23293/com.borah.manjit.myapplication D/mn:
>   https://myapplication6-55473.firebaseio.com/Games 09-10 13:34:59.184
>   23293-23293/com.borah.manjit.myapplication W/mn: Failed to read value.
>       com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Permission denied
>           at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError.toException(Unknown Source)
>           at com.borah.manjit.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onCancelled(MainActivity.java:40)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegf.zza(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzehy.zzbyc(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)

Comment: Is it showing any error in your logs?

Comment: It is showing a DatabaseException

Comment: please include it in your question

Comment: Please add your database structure and the exception that you are getting. Please also reponde with @.

Comment: @DominicOrim I have added the log

Comment: @AlexMamo I have already added the database structure as a snapshot

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct security rules?

Comment: everything seems okay. you should should check your google-services.json file if its details correspond with the details of your android app